# Consulta que devuelve valor mysql

Tags: mysql

Quiciera saber si hay alguna consulta en MYSQL que permita devolver un valor, en caso que de que la consulta sea afirmativa, como es ta consulta.

```
select usuario_ad, nombre, asignacion 
from usuarios 
where usuario_ad='danielad' and asignancion='paolaad';
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con que *devuelva un valor*? La consulta devuelve los valores del `SELECT`...  si encuentra algo o devuelve cero filas... ¿Qué quieres decir con que *sea afirmativa*?

Comment: que responda 1 o un 0, afirmativa pues que si exista valor

Comment: Eso depende. ¿Sólo te interesa que devuelva `1` ò `0` si encuentra o no datos, o te interesa también el valor de `usuario_ad, nombre, asignacion`? ¿Es desde MySQL mismo o estás trabajando en PHP u otro lenguaje?

Comment: No, solo un valor 1 o 0, esto es de eloquen laravel, pero de eso me cargo despues, solo necesito saber si se puede en sql normal, asi si se puede podria manejar esto con php.

Comment: Como te decía, son dos universos distintos. Si finalmente vas a trabajar con PHP, lo más correcto sería enviar esta consulta a la BD: **`select COUNT(*) total from usuarios where usuario_ad='danielad' and asignancion='paolaad';`**, recuperas por programación si devolvió `0` filas o `>=1` filas, para determinar si hay registros o no con ese criterio.

Comment: mmm.. si podria hacerlo asi... hay manera que desde una consulta, averiguar si el campo tiene valor o si simplemente es NULL?

Comment: Todo eso se puede hacer, por ejemplo con los `WHERE`. Pero no creo que lo mejor sea hacerlo como estás pensando. La vía más rápida y más segura para saber si una condición se cumple es usar `COUNT(*)` ...  si la única finalidad es saber si hay registros con esa condición. En el `WHERE` pones todos los criterios de filtro.

Comment: @zereft prueba de este modo `con el query builder pudiera ser asi: $data = \DB::table('usuarios') ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) total') ->where('usuario_ad', 'danielad') ->where('asignacion', 'paolaad') ->get(); if($data > 0){ return 1; }else{ return 0; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retomando la idea de @A.Cedano se me ocurre que con el query Builder lo hagas del modo siguiente

**CÓDIGO QUERY BUILDER**

```
$data = \DB::table('usuarios') 
           ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) total') 
           ->where('usuario_ad', 'danielad') 
           ->where('asignacion', 'paolaad') 
           ->get(); 

if($data > 0)
{ 
  return 1; 
}else{ 
  return 0; 
}
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

1. Hacemos uso de `selectRaw()` para hacer el `COUNT()` de la columna
2. Tu tienes el uso de un `WHERE` con el operador `AND` para hacer necesario que se cumplan 2 condiciones; aquí hacemos uso de dos métodos `WHERE`
3. Con un `if` hacemos una comprobación, si la variable que contiene la consulta es mayor a 0 entonces si existe data en caso contrario retornamos 0

**CÓDIGO CON ELOQUENT**

```
$data = ModelName::where('usuario_ad', 'danielad')
        ->where('asignacion', 'paolaad')
        ->count()
        ->get();

if($data > 0){
  return 1;
}else{
  return 0;
}
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

Puedes si estas usando algún modelo para la tabla `usuarios` asignarlo donde yo coloqué `ModelName` es decir sustituyelo

Comment: Gracias shadow, efectivamente estuve aplicando lo que dices a mi script y funciono perfecto, muchas gracias por la asesoria.